# REST API returns 400(Bad Request) when provided JSON input having HTML as a value

Tags: java, spring

I wanted to pass below JSON input to my REST API.

```
{
"title":"Login Page",
"termsCondition" : "<a href='SOMEURL'> Terms and Conditions </a>"
}
```

However, this gives me error 400 (Bad Request) before reaching to API code.
I am currently using application/json content type.

How should I allow API to accept above input JSON?
I tried escaping special chars from HTML content but it's not working

Comment: Pleae provide the code of your controller. Do you get any Exceptions / StackTraces within your server? Please provide these also.

Comment: Is the browser console showing any errors ?

Comment: Include the error too in question

Answer (score 1):

In spring you have the annotation [@RequestBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) which is used to map the content of the http request body to a parameter in a handler method.

So, to accept the json that you specified you need to have the following view model:

```
public RequestExample{
  private String title;
  private String termsCondtion;

  //constructors, getters, setters
}
```

and use it in a `POST` (or `PUT`) method type like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void testPostBody( @RequestBody RequestExample example){
  ..
}
```